# How scalable is MapReduce in the original functional languages?

Tags: functional-programming, hadoop, scalability, mapreduce, parallel-processing

The Map-Reduce programming model stems from the map and reduce functions which are present in functional languages like Lisp and Scheme dating back many many years.

I remember from university (early 90's) that even back then I was told Map-Reduce had advantages in terms of scalability.

At the moment we all know about Hadoop and the original from Google it was copied from.
What I was wondering about is what options exist in "old" functional languages to do Map-Reduce over at least a few compute nodes?

Or is this one of those features that looked good on paper but no one ever got around to actually building until Google did it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map/Reduce is a special case of **[data parallelism](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/cacm/cacm2.html)**.

Data parallelism (which is more than just `map` and `fold`) is widely used in high performance computing languages, and in parallel functional languages. Google and others have built a highly optimized (restricted) distributed programming model for their use case, but they're surely fully aware of the origins and state of this work elsewhere.

HPC languages, such as

- [Chapel](http://chapel.cray.com/index.html)
- [Fortress](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community)
- [X10](http://x10-lang.org/)
- [HPF](http://hpff.rice.edu/versions/hpf2/index.htm)

and purely functional languages, with full data parallelism:

- [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell)
- [NESL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/nesl.html)

all support a full data parallel programming model, for either distributed or multicore systems. In particular, Chapel, Fortress and X10 are aimed at *massive* scalability on the world's largest computer clusters. Many other languages support some notion of parallel map and fold (e.g. Erlang, Clojure, Scala, F#).

So, certainly Google popularized data parallelism, in its basic form as map/reduce, but that's not the end of the story.